# how change Username And Password to proxy

Tags: asp.net

I have username and password to login a web site but i need login with proxy
how can change username and pass to proxy
i can login to web site with this url www.mydomain.com?user=1&pass=2 or insert user and pass to login page
how i can login web site with HttpWebRequest in asp.net C#?

```
<code>
Encoding encode = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
HttpWebRequest Request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(Url);
HttpWebResponse Response = (HttpWebResponse)Request.GetResponse();


</code>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is well documented on MSDN, see [HttpWebRequest.Proxy Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.proxy.aspx).

> The local computer or application config file may specify that a
>   default proxy be used. If the Proxy property is specified, then the
>   proxy settings from the Proxy property override the local computer or
>   application config file and the HttpWebRequest instance will use the
>   proxy settings specified. If no proxy is specified in a config
>   file and the Proxy property is unspecified, the HttpWebRequest
>   class uses the proxy settings inherited from Internet Explorer on the
>   local computer. If there are no proxy settings in Internet Explorer,
>   the request is sent directly to the server.

There is also longer sample code, the most important part is:

```
WebProxy myProxy = new WebProxy();
myProxy.Address = "your proxy url";
myProxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("login", "password");
Request.Proxy = myProxy;
```